# Elastic Search v6.3: Query with filter never returns any matches

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm facing some challenges with Elastic Search. I want to query for by some text and then filter based on a category. I followed the [Elastic Search 6.3 Documentation for Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html) but my response for `ES` is always empty. I know for a fact that I have at least one entry that *should* match the request. Below I have posted my query to Elastic Search and the entry that I know is present in my Elastic Search index. Any help is very much appreciated.

**Query**

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 300,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": {
          "term": {"category": "Soups"}
        },
        "should": [
          {"term": {"instructions": "Matt"}},
          {"term": {"introduction": "Matt"}},
          {"term": {"recipe_name": "Matt"}},
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1,
        "boost": 1.0
      }
    }
  }
```

**Record Present in Elastic Search**

```
        {
            "_index": "recipes",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "QMCScWoBkkkjW61rD81v",
            "_score": 0.2876821,
            "_source": {
                "calories": 124,
                "category": "Soups",
                "cook_time": {
                    "hour": "2",
                    "min": "4"
                },
                "cooking_temp": "375",
                "cooking_temp_units": "°F",
                "creator_username": "virtualprodigy",
                "ingredients": [
                    {
                        "majorQuantity": "1 ",
                        "measuring_units": "teaspoon",
                        "minorQuantity": " ",
                        "name": "mett"
                    }
                ],
                "instructions": "instructions",
                "introduction": "intro",
                "prep_time": {
                    "hour": "1",
                    "min": "2"
                },
                "recipe_name": "Matt Test",
                "servings": 1
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are using term queries for instructions, introduction, and recipe name to all match _Matt_. Term queries match the term **exactly** [see docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-term-query.html), and none of those terms match _Matt_ exactly. introductions = "intro", instructions = "instructions", and recipe_name = "Matt Test". Try using a multi match query and an analyzer to break down the query and index into simple terms. There doesn't seem to be a problem with the filter you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fields are probably indexed using a standard analyser, which means they are split into tokens and lowercased. The [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) is an exact match and does not perform this analysis, so you are looking for 'Matt' and it only has 'matt'. You look for 'Soups' and it only has 'soups'. The easiest fix is to change your term queries into [match queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html). e.g:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 300,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "match": {
                    "category": "Soups"
                }
            },
            "should": [
                {"match": {"instructions": "Matt"}},
                {"match": {"introduction": "Matt"}},
                {"match": {"recipe_name": "Matt"}}
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're probably right. I will try this out this evening. Hopefully it work. I will also look into the different analyzers to see if I can upgrade my mapping.

Comment: Tried this out finally and it worked like a charm. I'll have to go back later and update my index analyzers for better searchable. For now, this will solve my need for a POC. Thanks so much